# Where place data file in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a web application and I want to save data in a file instead of in the database.

My doubt is, where I should save the file? If I save it under the public directory, I could refer them with the assets to make the correct URL, but in the public directory, any person could see the file writing the complete URL. This shouldn't be because de data is reserved.

I think about the var directory, but I couldn't use the assets to make the correct URL to get or manage the files.

Where I should save the files and how I get/manage them?

Comment: where do you wanna get/manage these files? at the server I'm guessing, then doesn't matter wherever you put these files outside, obviously, webroot/public/web folder of this application

Comment: For me it's not quite clear if you need to access it by URL from outside or is it fine to access it only from inside of application

Answer (score 2):

If the data-file is local and hosted on the server's file system, the most logical place to store something like that would be the `var` directory. Although nothing stops you from creating your own "var-like" directory and naming any way you like it. E.g. `data`. But I would follow the conventions and create `var/data`, easier for everyone.

That you can't use the `asset()` function is irrelevant, because a data-file is not a web asset, but an infrastructure concern.

A file like this should not have a URL at all, but you would only access it through it's file system path.

Comment: Data files should not be accessible via the web server. If you are accessing the file form a URL, is not a data-file (that you use instead of a DB) but a web asset. You do not have clear use-cases, I think.

Comment: Without knowing more about your use-case it's impossible to give a better answer. As it is, the answer is the correct one: data-files should not be on a publicly accessible place, and it's good to follow conventions and store this kind of file in `var`.

Comment: I'm still thinking that I need to refer the complete URL inside the code. Because of this, in Symfony2, I used the assets for files located in web directory. If I didn't do this, the file couldn't be load because the complete directory (including webroot) is not properly especified. I shouldn't refer explicity to "MyDomain" because in prod environment, the URL changes from the development environment. 
For example in Symfony2: 
in test -> localhost/MyDomain/web/data/file.txt
in prod->www.webserver/MyDomain/web/data/file.txt
Assets fill the URL before MyDomain {{assets ('data/file.txt')}}

Comment: You do not need to have a URL unless you want to USE THAT URL publicly. If you do not need access the data-file publicly, **you do not need a URL**. And a data-file **should not be publicly accessible**. Maybe you say data-file but you mean something else.

Comment: Probably I have explain my issue in a wrong way. My doubt without ussing assets is how I put the route (I refered as URL) of the file. I mean, if a want to create a data-file from the controller i should use "file_put_contents(../public/data/file.txt)". But what if I have a subdirectory in the Controller or Service directory? Then to create my data-file I should use "file_put_contents(../../public/data/file.txt)". With the assets, I'm triying to relativizes the directory from the public directory and only need to specify "file_put_contents(data/file.txt)". I hope it is well explained